# Accessing Panasonic MK5 Rear Camera using DShowLib.dll but it is not working after some time

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Please help me out on attached piece of code. 
Run this project on Panasonic Tablet model MK5. Click on start camera. Preview will work for first two time after that it(Preview) will stuck.
Here i am using DShowLib_86.dll as my application is running on 32bit OS. 
For first instance it seems that problem is with Direct Show library which is provided by Microsoft.

It was giving stack imbalance error which was because of calling convention that i resolved using CallingConvention.Cdecl or .SrdCall

Still Preview is not working on third time.

---

```
        private static extern IntPtr pCamInfo_GetConnectedCameraInfo_DotNET(ref int error, ref int numCameras);
        [DllImport("DShowLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Hi Sir,
Piece of code down below is causing the problem.
Here if i am selecting ActiveCamera.CameraFormat[1] then it is working as many time as i want. But preview is not much clear as this format is not having proper format for resolution.
But if i am selecting ActiveCamera.CameraFormat[0] then it is not working after two times of preview.
Point to be noted here is that we are using DShowLib.dll which is provided by Microsoft for camera functionalities. As our WPF in C# Windows application is running on 32bit OS so we are accessing DShowLib_86.dll.

```
private void InitCamera()
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (ActiveCamera != (Camera)null)
        {
            ActiveCamera.EndPreview();
            ActiveCamera.StartPreview(ActiveCamera.CameraFormats[0], this.ImageBox.Handle);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Camera[] cameras = Camera.Cameras;
                if (cameras != null)
                {
                    ActiveCamera = cameras[0];
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("No camera: ", ex, new object[0]);
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                ActiveCamera.StartPreview(ActiveCamera.CameraFormats[0], this.ImageBox.Handle);
                this.SaveButton.Enabled = true;
                this.CancelButton.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ActiveCamera = (Camera)null;
                this.SaveButton.Enabled = false;
                this.CancelButton.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: private static extern IntPtr pCamInfo_GetConnectedCameraInfo_DotNET(ref int error, ref int numCameras);
        [DllImport("DShowLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]                  With this i am not getting Stack Imbalance exception but Camera Preview is still not working

Comment: You should include your code in your question, ideally using formatting, rather than in a comment. You can [edit] the question to add it.

Comment: Are you closing the connection after each preview?  There may be a limit on the number of connection.  I would use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will show the status of all connections.  Check while you are running that status of the connection(s).

Comment: No it is not having anything with number of connections because with different camera format it it working fine i.e as many number of times i want.